# Android's elevation not working with different rounded-corners rectangle

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

> EDIT: suggested solutions here offer me to draw the shadows myself. I
>   don't want that as the view will be animated (translationZ will change
>   over time) and I would like to avoid rendering the shadows myself
>   during the animation. I would like some solution to **help
>   android-system recognize my shape as a background** for the elevation.
>   If no such solution will be found, the hard way will be subclassing a
>   ViewOutlineProvider with convexPath, but I would really like to avoid
>   this.

As the name of the question suggests, I have a problem getting android's elevation to work with a rectangle of different rounded-corners. (pictures added at the end of the question)

It does work when there is only 1 default radius, i.e with this example:

**rounded_rect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect"
        android:elevation="5dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I'm changing **rounded_rect.xml** to the following code, no shadows are being casted:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"
        />
</shape>
```

I have tried adding also `android:radius="5dp"` into the `<corners>` tag in **rounded_rect.xml** , but it didn't add shadows.

Any help would be much appreciated!

picture working with default radius for all corners:
[image: layout working with radius defined]

picture not working with different radius for each corner - no shadows:
[image: layout with different radiuses]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using my custom subclass of `ViewOutlineProvider` . in my subclass I calculated a `Path` that its `isConvex()` returns true, and used that path as the shadow.

Comment: please add some url's

Comment: You could have shared a code example...

Answer (score 2):

Refer this

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />

    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="3px">

    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />


    </shape>

</item>


</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It won't help me as I will need to change and animate the view, so that the shadows will need to change dynamically and here they are rendered statically at creation time.
I just need android system to recognize my shape.

Answer (score 0):

use [this](http://shapes.softartstudio.com/) online making tool this will help you to make shapes

in that at border radius

[image]

Comment: I don't have a problem creating shapes. I just need them to cast a shadow

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Apply this code. Set the button as per your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:topRightRadius="40dp"
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270"
                        android:endColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
                    <corners android:topRightRadius="40dp"
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp"
                        android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It won't help me as I will need to change and animate the view, so that the shadows will need to change dynamically and here they are rendered statically at creation time.
I just need android system to recognize my shape.